# How to adjust CV that should not contain any information that allows inferences on the genderof the applicant?

Tags: resume, gender

The application for a position that I am interested in requires a CV that does not contain any information that allows inferences on the gender of the applicant ("no picture, no first name, no e-mail address with first names etc")
However, coming from eastern Europe, my family name carries the suffix **ova**, which indicates that I am female. I can easily change my e-mail address, but what would you advise me to do with my list of publication, in which my surname appears among the names of other co-authors?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I think FirstPartOfName[Gender Indicating Suffix Removed] would be better.  It's clear that whoever wrote the application requirements wasn't aware of naming patterns like those used where Ema lives; and would probably be confused by your suggestion.  That said; if there's any way to do so, if possible contacting the employer via an email address/etc without a name to ask what they would prefer is probably the best option.

Comment: Can you ask the organization how to handle cases such as yours? There is no way to make Russian last names gender neutral since the suffix "ov" means "male". The only way they could make the CV's truly gender neutral is by removing the names and assigning ID numbers instead. And in your case, not including the list of your publications in your CV. You'll have to sort your issue out with the organization you are applying to since they were the one who came up with this rule.

Comment: Is it possible to use a pseudonym?  The important part is that they can uniquely identify you right?

Comment: Leaving off a list of publications (the bigger issue here, imho) that may add weight to your CV is a bad solution.  This employer is being cautious to the point of silliness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the following two things:

1. Hide the gender-identifying part(s) of your name with initials in resume and application.
2. Explain in the cover letter why you are doing this.

The rule asking applicants to not disclose their gender seems to be a "strict mode" implementation of a non-discrimination policy/law. Since most people's first name reveals their gender, they explicitly forbade its use in the resume and email address, but they did not foresee a situation where *both* first name and family name are gender-identifying.

To illustrate with example, if your name is Martina Navratilova, write your name as **M. N.** in the resume, and include a note in the cover letter:

> Since this job requires applicants to not disclose their gender, and family name is also gender-identifying, I have omitted both first name and family name in my resume and application.

Likewise, in your publications, use initials in place of your name.

> *The Most Awesome Research Paper*, M. N., Pete Sampras, Roger Federer, and Maria Sharapova.

Another option is to list your publications as below.

> *The Most Awesome Research Paper*, co-authored with Pete Sampras, Roger Federer, and Maria Sharapova.

Comment: "Martina" is definitely female. The requirement is explicit: "no first-names".

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan I had misunderstood the question, sorry for the previous rude comments. I hope this answer is better.

Comment: No worries. Having said that, putting in M.N. as the co-authors of her papers is not a bad idea at all. This makes the list of publications usable as part of the CV and the resume a more powerful screening tool. She might as well edit her CV to have just her initials, too. Let the organization figure out how to keep track of her initials versus her full full name when they get her documentation. However, I would float the concept by the organization to make sure that the organization find it acceptable.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan I did think of that, but in my experience, recruiters rarely respond to "meta" questions about the application process, especially if they are employees of the organization that is hiring (as against headhunters). Typically, they would just extract the resume from the applicant's email, and upload it to their database. It is borderline rude, but that's how the world goes a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are applying, I would not worry about your last name too much.  Many (most?) people from countries where Slavic names are not common do not understand what the 'ova' suffix means.  In the US, for example, there are quite a few women of Polish descent with last names ending in 'ski' rather than 'ska' and most are probably unaware that the ending is 'incorrect'.  Given that the requirement to make names gender neutral is restricted to hiding first names, I think it is safe to assume that whoever posted the ad is unfamiliar with Slavic last names and the fact that they can reveal the person's gender.